# Detecting dot pattern from output of a scanner

Tags: c, image-processing, opencv

I am new to image processing. I have an image of `bmp` format and `.bin` files for a scanner output. The bin file has the `hex` values or raw data.

First i will explain the process. We use 13 digit numbers. Each number has a pattern represented in dot format. say, a 13 digit number will have 20 dots. Position of each dot depend on the digit. This is the `encryption` part. Now these dots are printed repeatedly. These are scanned using a scanner which gives the above mentioned files as the output.

Next step is to process those outputs to give back the 13 digit number. I am using `openCV` and `C`. Can someone give me some ideas on how to do this. I cannot post the bin file. But the contents of the bin file is in this format:

> 10 78 84 88 84 84 8c 88 88 8c 8c 90 88 88 8c 8c 90 90 88 90 8c 8c 8c 8c 8c 94 90 90 8c 90 90 94 8c 8c

I have added the output of the canny edge detection applied on the image.

[image: output of canny edge detection done on the image]

Thanks in advance...!

Comment: If you post the link to the image, someone with the right privilege will include it in your question for you :)

Comment: added the output of the canny detection done on the image using openCV

Comment: I don't think I'm totally clear as to what is being asked for. What do you mean by "detect dot pattern?" Is there something you are trying to compare it to? Do you want to know if the dots are there/isolate the dots?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really an opencv user. However, assuming you want to extract the dot regions, a quick dirty way to go about this is to identify connected components in the binary image with canny edge detection. [See this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling).

Once you've labelled all connected components, you can check the [circularity](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html) of each one

Then apply a filter for circularity and or area (calculated as the sum of 1s in each connected component) of each connected component. Only those which pass the filter are your dots.

This probably isn't the best way to do it because dots merged onto the outer circle will probably be filtered out, but if you only care about the isolated dots it should work in principal. Also, you probably want to threshold your image appropriately rather than applying edge detection

Good luck